# Parametrized like query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to create this query as parametrized query.

```
var query = ["Match (name:Name)-[r:IN_CLASS]->(class:Class)-[r1:HAS_STUDENTS]->(s:Student) where id(s)=",rollno," and lower(s.Name)=~'.*",name,".*' RETURN id(s),s.Name limit 5"].join('');
```

I have tried this code but it is giving error :

```
var query = ["Match (name:Name)-[r:IN_CLASS]->(class:Class)-[r1:HAS_STUDENTS]->(s:Student) where id(s)=",rollno," and lower(s.Name)=~'.*{name}.*' RETURN id(s),s.Name limit 5"].join('');

db.query(query , {name : name} , function(err,results){
    if (err) return callback(err);
    if(results){
        return callback(null,results);
    }
    else{
        return callback(null,false);
    }
});
```

Please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Can you post your error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have parameters that are part of a literal. You've tried

```
... WHERE ... lower(s.Name)=~'.*{name}.*'
```

Instead the whole regex expression needs to be the parameter value:

```
... WHERE ... lower(s.Name)=~ {name}
```

You need to concatenate your value with `.*` to `.*<value>.*` on the client side and pass this in as parameter value.

**Edit:**

You can also concatenate in Cypher:

```
... WHERE ... lower(s.Name)=~'.*'+{name}+'.*'
```

And for case insensitive regexps use:

```
... WHERE ... s.Name =~'(?i).*'+{name}+'.*'
```